# Clip Data Layer to only include continental United States

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, arcswat

I'm very much a beginner to ArcMap. Is there an easy way I can clip the Continental United States from this data layer and get rid of Alaska, Hawaii, and the other islands.

I saw some tutorials using ArcSwat. Would that be a useful option? I have ArcMap 10.6.1 and I know the ArcSwat tool only goes to ArcMap 10.4. I'm using a work computer and am not sure that I would be able to get an older version of ArcMap.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a Definition Query?  Just right-click the layer in the Table of Contents --> Properties --> Definition Query tab.  From there you can exclude or filter out certain features based on their attributes... in this case, something like NAME NOT IN ('Hawaii', 'Alaska')

Comment: I ended up finding a way to clip the layer. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

You won't be able to use [Clip](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/clip-function.htm) to extract a continental US unless you already have another continental US feature. You can, however, [Select](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/selecting-features-interactively.htm) and [Export](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/an-overview-of-exporting-data.htm) the features you need.

1. Choose the **Select by Rectangle** tool.

[image]

2. With the Select by Rectangle tool, draw a rectangle around the continental US.

[image]

3. After you complete the rectangle, your selected features will be highlighted in cyan.

[image]

4. Right-click on your layer and choose **Data/ Export Data...**.

[image]

5. Make sure you export only **Selected Features**. Choose a suitable output location and feature class. Here, I'm illustrating using a shapefile (.shp) as the feature class storage format. Shapefiles are relatively easy to work with, but they do have [certain limitations](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm) you may need to address at some point.

[image]

6. When prompted, add the exported data to your map.

[image]

7. Disable (uncheck) your original layer and leave your new layer checked to show only the continental US.

[image]

Comment: I ended up finding a a way to clip the layer using this rectangle method. Thanks

Comment: @StaceyM great! If appropriate, please mark this answer as the accepted answer. Or, if your method differed, contribute your own answer and mark that as accepted.